# I can't paint the model with Texture Paint

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, uv, texture-painting

I can't paint the head model I made with Sculpting with the Texture Painting panel. But I can paint on another model. What is the problem here?

Link: [https://dosya.co/yu74boitf245/yaratık.blend.html](https://dosya.co/yu74boitf245/yarat%C4%B1k.blend.html)

[image]

Comment: In the file you share you haven't given any material to your object (and in that material you need to create an Image Texture with a new image)

Comment: sorry i posted the wrong link.

Comment: @moonboots The link has been updated. I reloaded the project.

Comment: Can you check the link? I can't paint over the head.

Comment: sorry I can't test your object, it's too high in polygons, do you really want to paint on this object? You should better create a low-poly before, and bake your high-poly to the low-poly, then paint on the low-poly